# Chart.js отчет по неделям, дням и месяцам

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, angularjs

Используя линейный график от [chartjs.com](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart) 
Проблема в группировке отчета, сервер присылает в виде к примеру 30 дней(по сути дни уже приходят) отчета

```
var data = [[1446440400, 21], [1446440400, 16], [1446440400, 32]] и т.д.
```

Длина массива data допустим 30.
Вопрос: как динамически без запросов к сервверу, можно вывести отчет по неделям\месяцам? Какие манипуляции с data надо проводить? Может вы порекомендуете другой график с подобным функционалом? 
Аналог есть на flurry
[отчет по дням](http://prntscr.com/9bnzd2) и 
[отчет по неделям](http://prntscr.com/9bnzoh)

Comment: Я так понял, вам нужно зуммирование на графике? Посмотрите flot.js: http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/visitors/index.html

Comment: Да, это оно, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал посмотреть эти толстые библоитеки (примеры по твоему запросу):

- [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series)
  платный  для комерческого использования.
- [d3](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4015254)
  полностью бесплатный

Масса различных настроек, которые можно комбинировать бдур с другом +много примеров.
*Если в апликации будет не однотипный график - то советую взять одну из предложеных библиотек.

Comment: Спасибо. Второй пример довольно таки интересен, возьму на заметку  ;-) Просто уже заюзал flot.js