# Самая легкая-быстрая библиотека вывода графиков?

Tags: javascript

Какая самая примитивная библиотека для вывода графиков на javascript существует?

Отрисовка нескольких линий по датам, указать названия для осей, выводить легенды(названия линий по цвету), максимальный охват платформ(браузеров).

Чтобы мало весила, быстро выводила и не грузила браузер и сеть.
Использовал jqplot, но он огромный с кучей функционала и тормозит.

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading там в примере под два ляма точек

Comment: Я уже когда то советовал [графики](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472805/chart-js-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC/473466#473466),
думаю будет полезно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я недавно тоже искал, в итоге забил и сам написал быстренько (используя canvas). На график ушло строк всего строк 50, примерно так.

```
Graphic={
    time:10,
    init:function(){
        this.canvas=document.getElementById("graph");
        this.canvas.height=1000;
        this.canvas.width=document.body.clientWidth-20;
        this.pp=this.canvas.getContext('2d');

        Graphic.pp.fillStyle='#000000';                         
        //Оси
        Graphic.pp.fillRect(10,10,1,Graphic.canvas.height-20);
        Graphic.pp.fillRect(10,10,Graphic.canvas.width-20,1);
        //отметки и надписи на осях
        var i=100;
        while(i-->2){
            if(!(i%10)){
                Graphic.pp.fillText(i+'',0,i*10);
                Graphic.pp.fillRect(7,i*10,7,2);11
                Graphic.pp.fillRect(10,i*10,Graphic.canvas.width-20,0.5);
            }else Graphic.pp.fillRect(8,i*10,5,1);
        }

        var i=~~(Graphic.canvas.width/10);
        while(i-->2){
            if(!(i%10)){
                Graphic.pp.fillText(i.toString()+'s',i*10,7);                                   
                Graphic.pp.fillRect(i*10,7,2,7)
            }else Graphic.pp.fillRect(i*10,8,1,5);
        }
    },
    shot:function(stat){
        //Отрисовку следующей точки по координатам this.time и полученным данным из stat я опущу
        this.time++;
    }
}
Graphic.init();
app.socket.on('stat',Graphic.shot);
```

Как всегда, самая быстрая и гибкая библиотека - это VanillaJS)